# Why so many time out from Google related URLs from time to time?

Tags: google-tag-manager

My website uses Google Ads Conversion and Google Analystics. From time to time, I will see Chrome reports errors in accessing Google related URLs, such as

```
GET https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

A screenshot is put below:
[image]

THe error is generated from Google Tag Manager with the following URL:

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-1071615551&l=dataLayer&cx=c
```

I am curious why this will occur so frequently since Google has the best server and network connection in the world?

I have seen some report indicating Google Server is the best, for example:

1. Google CDN is the 2nd fast, see https://www.cdnperf.com/

Another report is not in English so I do not put it here.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with various Google services for a while now. Have never seen a timed out or a different kind of errorous hit except in cases:

1. Sudden client connection loss. Especially with mobile traffic.
2. Second Most popular issue - adblockers. They tend to block tracking too. Often by interfering with the network requests, resulting in network errors that then surface in datadog/dynatrace and whatnot.
3. When it's impossible for the client to play its encryption part, which is likely either due to there being a middle man sniffing the traffic, or, which is actually more common, the client having a completely wrong date. This should be quite a rare occasion
4. When there's a firewall-like filtering in place blocking requests to Google servers. Even more rare in my experience.

Comment: For adblocker, our website does not contains any add tracking, except for the scripts from Google Ads and Google Analystics.

Comment: For firewall, we are using Cloudflare and I have set the Firewall to "Essentially Off", which is the lowest level available.

Comment: Google ads and google analytics is what an addblocker would block. You don't need to contain any add tracking. Your firewall is irrelevant. I meant clients' firewalls.